# sql query, plsql needed?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have three tables, customer, account and orders.

A customer can have many orders, so orders have the customer_id foreign key.

A customer can have many accounts, but an account only can have to a customer, so the account has customer_id foreign key.

The table account has a attribute called defaulter, that can be TRUE or FALSE.

Wish to make the following query:

- All customer orders with two defaulter accounts.

It can be done with SQL or is PLSQL needed?

thank you

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shows no effort on the part of the poster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PL/SQL is not needed. This query can be done with a trivial SQL DQL query.

Either,

1. JOIN customers to accounts twice, looking for different accounts (for the same customer) meeting the "defaulter account" criteria, or
2. JOIN customers to accounts once and use GROUP BY (on the customer) HAVING COUNT >= 2 where the "defaulter account" criteria is met, or
3. JOIN customers to accounts, GROUP on customer and apply an aggregate COUNT when the "defaulter account" criteria is met with a COUNT (CASE..). Use an outer query to select when the COUNT >= 2, or move the aggregate count into the WHERE clause.

If needing to find "exactly two" (or another number), the latter two approaches are more flexible, and HAVING COUNT is probably the most idiomatic.

Comment: Lo he logrado: SELECT p.id_pedido, COUNT(cu.id_cuenta),p.id_cliente FOM pedido p, cuenta cu WHERE cu.id_cliente = p.id_cliente AND cu.morosa='YES' GROUP BY p.id_pedido, p.id_cliente HAVING COUNT(cu.id_cuenta)=2; Gracias!